# Making a One-Time Boot Script

Tags: perl, systemd

In systemd, I need to be able to create a script, stage it, and execute it on next boot, deleting it once it's been executed and removing the service.

I've created some Perl to build the unit file and to stage the script that will execute and clean the other parts. For some reason, I can `sudo systemctl start onetimerun` and the relevant thing happens immediately. However, even after a `sudo systemctl enable onetimerun` it still fails to start on boot.

This is the Perl code I have that should build the relevant environment for running the script in /tmp/one-time-run/scripts/

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

my $unitFile = <<'END_MESSAGE';
[Unit]
Description=Ooe-time executor for ad-hoc boot scripts
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/tmp/one-time-run/runwrangler.pl

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
END_MESSAGE

my $runScript = <<'END_MESSAGE';
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use Data::Dumper;
my @scriptFiles = map { $_ =~ s/\s//gr } `for i in \$(ls /tmp/one-time-run/scripts/*.sh); do test -x "\$i" -a ! -d "\$i" && echo "\$i"; done;`;
print Dumper @scriptFiles;
foreach my $file (@scriptFiles) {
  if(!(system("$file"))) {
     print "Failed to run $file\n";
  }
  else {
    system("rm $file");
  }
}
system('rm /tmp/one-time-run/runwrangler.pl');
system('rm /run/systemd/system/onetimerun.service');
END_MESSAGE

unless(open UNITFILE, '>/run/systemd/system/onetimerun.service') {
  die "\nUnable to create unit file.\n";
}

print UNITFILE $unitFile;
close UNITFILE;

system('mkdir /tmp/one-time-run/');

unless(open WRANGLER, '>/tmp/one-time-run/runwrangler.pl') {
  die "\nUnable to create wrangler script.\n";
}

print WRANGLER $runScript;
close WRANGLER;

system('chmod +x /tmp/one-time-run/runwrangler.pl');
system('systemctl daemon-reload');
system('systemctl enable onetimerun');
```

I expect any script in /tmp/one-time-run/scripts/ to be run and subsequently removed before deleting the unit file and the wrangler deleted.

Instead, nothing seems to happen on boot.

Comment: "Nothing seems to happen on boot" is not an adequate description of a problem. Did you even check if the script is run? If so, it would have created a file or generated an error message at the very least.

Comment: This seems _very_ risky from a security perspective. How are you going to mitigate the risk of everybody being able to write to that path?

Comment: @ikegami, the script doesn't run as far as I can tell. journalctl yields:
```
-- Reboot --
Apr 22 16:35:31 <hostname> systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit onetimerun.service, ignoring: Unit not found.
Apr 22 16:35:31 <hostname> systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit onetimerun.service, ignoring: Unit not found.
```
I put a script in the relevant directory to plop something in my homedir, but it did nothing. As far as I can tell, though, the way I'm targeting things isn't unusual.

Comment: @manchicken: You're not wrong; it's definitely a bit sketch. The only thing that makes it secure-ish is that I'm using it myself, setting it up, and immediately rebooting. Idea being that I can do a thing, stage something to happen immediately after reboot, then reboot to complete it. A savvy malicious actor would watch for changes in that dir and write something to it between the script run and the reboot, but that will be seconds at most and the service deletes itself once completed. (The whole goal is to leave the system config untouched post-exec.)

Comment: Re "*the script doesn't run as far as I can tell*", In that case, this isn't a Perl problem. It's not even a programming problem, so you're not even on the right site. Most importantly, you've provide no information about the problem. (What system, why you think it should be executed at startup, etc)

Comment: This is certainly not the only sysadmin-y problem on this site, and there are certainly concerns around syntax for which I am requesting help. If you don't have the familiarity with systemd to understand, given where I'm putting the script and how I'm enabling it from within the Perl, why I'd expect it to work on boot then that's fine, but this is absolutely a reasonable place for this. I've even given details regarding the fact that it does work when I fire it off manually. This would be sufficient detail for anyone working meaningfully with systemd.

Comment: Re "*This is certainly not the only sysadmin-y problem on this site*", Irrelevant. HOWEVER. What you didn't make clear is that there are two scripts, one that sets up the other to run on reboot. In that case, it could be a Perl problem. But if so, you didn't say which step is failing. Is that the case? Is one of the steps failing (A programming problem), or is it a question of not knowing what to do? I can help you with the former but not the latter. (Note that it's a fluke that I noticed your reply because you didn't tag me.)

Comment: As an aside, using `tmp` seems really weird. On some of the machines I've used, that gets wiped on reboot. And others didn't allow executables as a security precaution.

Comment: @ikegami, good note on /tmp/; I've tried setting the new directory to live in /etc/. I still get the "cannot add dependency" error.
When I fire it off manually using systemctl, I get:
`Apr 23 17:30:47 <nope> systemd[1]: Starting one-time executor for ad-hoc boot scripts...`
`Apr 23 17:30:47 <nope> runwrangler.pl[5710]: $VAR1 = '/etc/one-time-run/scripts/testThing.sh';`
`Apr 23 17:30:47 <nope> runwrangler.pl[5710]: Failed to run /etc/one-time-run/scripts/testThing.sh`
`Apr 23 17:30:47 <nope> systemd[1]: Started one-time executor for ad-hoc boot scripts.`
This looks like a systemd issue.